# Working on old codebase running on IIS and I can't figure out if the current build even works?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, iis

This feels like a very beginner-level question (I do not come from a C#/.NET background at all) so I am sorry if this is too simple. I have been looking for hours to find an answer and I can't find anything.

I have begun working on a website developed about one year ago it is currently deployed, but I'm starting to become curious that the code in the deployment folder isn't buildable? I worked on some stuff locally (directly cloning the deploy folder on the server) and it doesn't really work properly, but I assumed it was because the environment is different.

I tested this tiny change locally (slightly alters the data that is being inserted into the database) and it was working perfect. I tried to deploy it and it doesn't work correctly. After pulling in the one file I changed, the website still operates exactly the same as before.

My question is, what happens with an IIS deployed app if you make a change that makes the app unbuildable (some type of compile-time error like a syntax thing, even)? Does it continue running the previously buildable version? I feel like that would make sense, but I am unfamiliar with how things work in this environment.

Comment: You have to publish each build you want to deploy. Simply changing source code & breaking it will not effect the production build?

Comment: The short answer is, it depends.  Some things (.aspx pages and .cshtml) are *dynamically* built when the server needs them, so they may well have c# code in them and changing this on the server will have immediate effect.  code in code-behind files (`.cs` files) will generally always have to be compiled into a DLL, and that DLL is deployed instead.  We don't know enough about your app and your changes to give good advice right now...

Comment: Does IIS have something in it that can rebuild the app for you, or do you need to use something like MSBuild? I tried using MSBuild yesterday in the directory with the source code (called 'physical path' I believe in IIS?) and it gave some errors, but like I hadn't even made any changes yet. Am I just out of luck if the previous devs didn't really use proper version control?

Comment: @GPW The change I want to make is in a .cs file (a controller, specifically). Is MSBuild probably what I should be using?

Comment: @ishaboi Visual Studio should be able to handle building and publishing for you.  I *strongly* advise you to get the site working in a staging environment (which could be hosted on your machine, but ideally a different one, or azure or something) before trying to update a live site....